Postman websocket to Powershell
I can create via postman a socket connection to a server. It requires upfront to create a bearer token via Rest Command.
I am trying now replicate the same with powershell to automate these steps. The token I can still receive but then creating the Socket connection throws me an error:
Exception              : System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException: Unable to connect
to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func2 endFunction, Action1 endAction,  Task1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)

My script looks like this - the token is correct that I got - cannot really find anything around that.
  $url = "ws://myserver/test/test"
    $bearer = "Bearer $token"
    $WS = New-Object System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket
    $CT = New-Object System.Threading.CancellationToken                                                
    $WS.Options.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", $Bearer)
    
    #Get connected
    $Conn = $WS.ConnectAsync($URL, $CT)


I found the problem. The URL was not OK. In Postman the URL can start with ws:// for powershell it needs to be wss://
so correct URL would be
$url = "wss://myserver/test/test"
